# How do I stop Postgres from outputting record creation details to the terminal (rails c/dev mode)? The 1000's of "puts" are slowing down my program

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, shell

I know that all of this "putting" to my command line is slowing down my rails server, even in development mode which is where I am. How do I stop it from doing this?

Right now I'm manually adding files to my database, and I don't need to be in production mode....I've never been in production mode...I'm just a student! But I **know** this thing is slowing down my program while its running. I've seen how fast programs when when they don't have to "talk" to the display. How do I abbreviate all of this verbosity?

Comment: haha 5-10 minutes after I started asking this question (formatting, going back and forth on how to ask it, categories, etc), my rails program is STILL running because it has to output all this crap to the command line

Comment: the command line....I'm running these commands from the rails console

Comment: If you're using `gnome-terminal` on a machine that doesn't have accelerated text and graphics you're probably right: it is slowing your computer down a LOT. I've seen `gnome-terminal`+`Xorg` 90% of the CPU before. I wouldn't be surprised if `Terminal.app` and `cmd.exe` weren't exactly fast either. If you're on Linux/unix, try good old `xterm`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set `config.log_level` in config/environments/development.rb

By default it will be `:debug` in development, setting it to `:info` will stop query logging. If it's just part of your code you wish to silence you could instead do

```
ActiveRecord::Base.silence do
  #code executed here will not log queries
end
```